# Does a function inside jQuery constructor do anything different?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I feel like I've only ever seen this here on SO, but I can't seem to find any documentation on it. The code I am talking about is stuff like this:

```
$(function foo(){
    alert('foo');
});
```

Is there anything to that or is that just something that novices do because they think jQuery is a language? There is no scope change. It just seems completely unnecessary. Is there any method that you can invoke on this like:

```
$(function foo(){ alert('foo'); }).someMethod();
```

The closest thing I can think of is [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), but that doesn't use this syntax. Am I right, is this completely unnecessary?

Comment: It's equivalent to `$(document).ready(function(){})` [Documented here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does $(function() {} ); do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642442/what-does-function-do)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does $(function() {} ); do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642442/what-does-function-do)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how you invoke a function *after DOM initialization*.  It's equivalent to

```
$().ready(function() { ... } );
```

**EDIT:** From the documentation:

> All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> ```
>  - $(document).ready(handler)
>  - $().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
>  - $(handler)
> ```

See: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @lbstr -- thanks for the corrections, but is "syntaxes" really the plural of "syntax".  Wiktionary agrees with you, but I can't help thinking "syntaces"...

Comment: @malvolio I don't think syntax is an English word, so it's different pluralized (I know that's not a word, but I'm Dutch).

Comment: @Malvolio -- I agree. Syntaxes looks weird and Chrome underlines it as a typo. But, I guess the plural of tax is taxes, so we'll have to live with it :) I guess I could have said: "Pick a syntax from the list below; they're all the same".

Comment: @lbstr -- there's a long pointless joke that ends, "The zookeeper wrote, 'Enclosed please find one mongoose.  Also enclosed: another mongoose'."