# What does $(function() { ....}) do in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking through some source code and saw this:

```
$(function() {
    $('li.link').css('cursor', 'pointer')
    .click(function() {
        window.open ($('a', this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

Can someone explain what that does, selecting an anonymous function? I don't care about the body of the function; I'm just interested what `$(function() { ...})` does.

Comment: its an alias for $(document).ready()

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662778/what-is-the-difference-between-these-jquery-ready-functions

Comment: @Quentin A better duplicate would be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642442/what-does-function-do

Answer (score 2):

It is a short notation for the `ready()` function in jQuery.

It is documented on that functions doc-entry: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

> All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:

```
$( document ).ready( handler ) 
$().ready( handler ) (this is not recommended)
$( handler )
```

> There is also `$(document).on( "ready", handler )`, deprecated as of jQuery 1.8…

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [jQuery source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/15a609f7663c4348ab7f1acbc9e566ec20bb717c/src/core/init.js#L101) you will see these lines:

```
// HANDLE: $(function)
// Shortcut for document ready
} else if (jQuery.isFunction(selector)) {
    return typeof rootjQuery.ready !== "undefined" ? rootjQuery.ready(selector) :
    // Execute immediately if ready is not present
    selector(jQuery);
}
```

So this is `Shortcut for document ready`.