# What "jQuery(function($) {" is for?

Tags: jquery, syntax

I'm pretty new to web programming.

Looking for a jQuery function I found something like:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#EleId1').click(function () {
        //do stuff
    }
    $('#EleId2').click(function () {
        //do other stuff
    }

});
```

**BUT** if I remove "`jQuery(function($) {`" and the final "`});`" all is still working and I have no errors in the console.

So my question about "`jQuery(function($) {`" is:
Is it recommended (as best practice or for a more readable code) or is it needed for other reasons?

**EDIT** 
In the similar question "jQuery" is missing so it doesn't seems an identical question to the ones not knowing that "$" is equivalent of "jQuery" as explained in the below comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642442/what-does-function-do

Comment: @luxdvie sorry I didn't find that question. Anyway "jQuery" is missing in the other question syntax

Comment: @luxdvie not quite. This is an incomplete snippet because it's missing the IIFE `(jQuery)` injection at the end. The parameter `$` is undefined

Comment: @SterlingArcher It doesn't need it. It's calling the jQuery function, and it calls its function argument as a callback.

Comment: @SterlingArcher This is equivalent to `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ... });`

Comment: I know it's the equivalent, but it's never passed in that callback, no? `jQuery($ => { ... })(jQuery);`

Comment: @genespos move your code to the `<head>` section of your page.  With `doc.ready` (`$(function() {`) it still works, without it - your click events don't work.  You wrap your code in `$(function() { ` so that it runs when the document is ready.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does $(function() {} ); do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642442/what-does-function-do)

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @freedomn-m and what is "jQuery" for?

Comment: "jQuery" = "$" - `jQuery(function()` is the same as `$(function()`  - because other libraries used "$" you can explicitly use `jQuery` so you don't get the conflict: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: If you're asking what the `$` in `jQuery(function($)` is, it's also jQuery.  jQuery passes itself in the function.  `$` is normally a global, but by passing it in, it becomes a local, which also allows you to ignore conflicts as, inside your function `$` becomes jQuery instead of the other library.   As you don't have another library, you can use `$` outside the function as well (as it's global).

Comment: @freedomn-m OK, This was the answer! Thanks ;) Why don't you post it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code:

```
jQuery(function() {
```

is shorthand for

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
```

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

`jQuery` vs `$` : "jQuery" = "$" - `jQuery(function()` is the same as `$(function()` - because other libraries use "$" you can explicitly use jQuery so you don't get the conflict.

> by default, jQuery uses $ as a shortcut for jQuery. Thus, if you are using another JavaScript library that uses the $ variable, you can run into conflicts with jQuery.

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

So you might use `jQuery(function` instead of `$(function` incase $ is defined elsewhere.

---

So to the code in the question, which is slightly different from other questions, the function call has a parameter that passes jQuery itself, so the code in the question:

```
jQuery(function($) {
```

ensures that all the code inside the function has access to `$`, while the code *outside* the function may or may not have `$` defined to a different library.

This can be demonstrated by use of a different variable in place of the `$` above:

```js
jQuery(function(replacementJquery) {
  replacementJquery("#id").text("updated")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='id'>original</div>
```

If you aren't use another library that uses `$` then you can safely use:

```
$(function() {
```

if you are writing a library that may be used with other libraries in addition to jQuery, then use:

```
jQuery(function($) {
```

and safely use `$` inside the function