# What is the best solution for scrollWidth problem?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**In Chrome console:**

```
$('.table-responsive').width(); //working
$('.table-responsive')[0].scrollWidth; //working
```

**In code while rendering HTML:**

```
$('.table-responsive').width(); //working
$('.table-responsive')[0].scrollWidth; //not-working
```

> Cannot read property 'scrollWidth' of undefined

Comment: ... use `width()` instead of `scrollWidth`?

Comment: Thanks, @MehdiDehghani, please post your answer so I can approve it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If code works on browser's console (*aka dev tools*) and doesn't work withing your JS code, that means (*in most cases*) your JS code runs before DOM/HTML is actually loaded.

You have 2 options:

1. Put your `script` tag on bottom of the page (*just before `</body>`*)
2. Use jQuery's [.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/), example:

`$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`

Which is equivalent to the recommended way of calling:

`$(function() { ... });`

Related helpful question, here on SO: [What does $(function() {} ); do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642442/what-does-function-do)

Comment: Thanks, @MehdiDehghani. Can you please up-vote my question and remove this negativity, I don't know why someone marked it with minus points.

Comment: @zarpio done! down voters always should say why, but sometimes the don't.