# jQuery code is not running with $(function(){...}); but will run without it

Tags: javascript, jquery, referenceerror

I'm very new to jQuery, but from what I've read, this doesn't make sense to me. Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
    function grid() {
        $("#main").hide();
    }
});

<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="numbers.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="main" style="height:90vh; width: 90vw; background-color:lightgray">
      <button onclick="grid()">grid</button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

When I put`$(function(){...});` around my code, it never runs and the console returns `ReferenceError: grid is not defined`, but if I remove `$(function(){...});` then everything runs fine.

Comment: Just remove it. `grid()` needs to be in global window scope in order to be accessed by `onclick`. If you have other jQuery inside it....move grid() outside

Comment: That's one of the reasons why you should not use inline event handlers (`onclick="grid()"`) but use `$('selector').on('click', grid)` at the place where `grid`  is visible to attach the event listener.

Comment: [What does $(function() {} ); do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642442/what-does-function-do): The code inside of it is executed when the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 3):

The code within `$(function() { })` has its own scope, so when you define a function within that, that function only exists within that scope.  However, you have:

```
<button onclick="grid()">grid</button>
```

Which looks for a function called "grid" in the global scope (where it doesn't exist).

Ideally, if you are using jQuery, you would do something more like:

```
<button id="grid">grid</button>

$(function(){
    $('#grid').on('click', function() {
        $("#main").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call a javascript function or define onClick listener of button inside `$(document).ready`

```js
// using jquery 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#grid').click(function(){
        $("#main").hide();
    });
});

// using javascript function
function grid(){
   document.getElementById('main').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="numbers.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main" style="height:90vh; width: 90vw; background-color:lightgray">
      <button id="grid">grid</button>
       <button onclick="grid()">grid2</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```